# What can be the appropriate code for input shown below. Its showing rum time error (NZCE)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

This code shows run time error as NZEC. Tried both the ways by input() and raw_input still shows error.

```
    # A = int(input('Enter the amount of A: '))
    # B = int(input('Enter the amount of B: '))
    A, B = raw_input().split(" ")
    A = int(A)
    B = int(B)
    if (A > 0 and B > 0):
        print('The mixture is a solution: ')
    elif (A == 0):
        print('The mixture is Liquid: ')
    elif (B == 0):
        print('The mixture is Solid: ')
    else:
        print('Invalid Entry')
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 there are no `raw_input` because all inputs are raw_input.
Given that the code works correctly and doesn't throw an error:

```
A = int(input('Enter the amount of A: '))
B = int(input('Enter the amount of B: '))
if (A > 0 and B > 0):
    print('The mixture is a solution: ')
elif (A == 0):
    print('The mixture is Liquid: ')
elif (B == 0):
    print('The mixture is Solid: ')
else:
    print('Invalid Entry')
```